# How to update the element color and sort it based on added string on the element using angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have name list iterating with ng options in multi select list box. When an option is clicked and a green check box is selected "green" string will be added to the element and its color is updated to green and sorted to the bottom of the list. I want to do this using angular directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/aastha/PMg7d/

```
.directive('changeColor', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var color;
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
          console.log("attrs.ngModel",attrs.ngModel);
          console.log("VALUE",value);
        if (value.name && value.name.indexOf("Green") != -1) {
            console.log("INSIDE GREEN");
            color = 'green';
            myStyle = {color:'green'};
            scope.style={"color":"green"}
        } else if (value.name && value.name.indexOf("Blue") != -1) {
            console.log("INSIDE BLUE");
            color = 'blue';
            myStyle = {color:'blue'};
            scope.style={"color":"blue"}
        } else {
            console.log("DEFAULT RED");
            color ='red';
            myStyle = {color:'red'};
        }

      }, true);
    }

}
})
;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aastha/PMg7d/

Answer (score 0):

I resorted using ng-repeat and custom sort functions.
http://jsfiddle.net/PMg7d/4/

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

     $scope.colors = [
        { id: '1', name: 'color1' },
        { id: '2', name: 'color2' },
        { id: '3', name: 'color3' },
        { id: '4', name: 'color4' },
        { id: '5', name: 'color5' },
        { id: '6', name: 'color6' },
        { id: '7', name: 'color7' }
        ];
    $scope.selectedColor = $scope.colors[0];
    $scope.style={"color":"red"}

    $scope.colorClick = function (color) {
        $scope.selectedColor = color;
        console.log("ID", $scope.selectedColor);
    }
    $scope.addGreen = function (){
        if (!$scope.green) {
        $scope.selectedColor.name = $scope.selectedColor.name.concat(" (Green)");
        } else {
            $scope.selectedColor.name = $scope.selectedColor.name.replace(" (Green)","");
        }
    }
    $scope.addBlue = function (){
        if (!$scope.blue) {
            $scope.selectedColor.name = $scope.selectedColor.name.concat(" (Blue)");
        } else {
            $scope.selectedColor.name = $scope.selectedColor.name.replace(" (Blue)","");
        }
    }

    $scope.greenSort = function (color) {
        return color.name.indexOf("Green")
    }

    $scope.blueSort = function (color) {
        return color.name.indexOf("Blue")
    }

})
.directive('changeColor', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var color;
      scope.$watch('color.name', function (value) {
        if (value.indexOf("Green") != -1) {
           console.log("INSIDE GREEN");
           scope.style={"color":"green"}
        } else if (value.indexOf("Blue") != -1) {
            scope.style={"color":"blue"}
        } else {
            scope.style = {color:'red'};
        }
      }, true);
    }     
}
})
;
```